# Read .txt file into a multi dimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, file

The example .txt data is:

```
20|Charlotte Aaaa|XXXX*SALE*O9
60|Peggy Bbbbb|XXXX*SALE*O8
25|Ashley Ccccc|XXXX*SALE*O7
103|Andrew Ddddd|XXXX*SALE*O1
51|Sally EEeee|XXXX*SALE*O6
9|Richard Fffff|XXXX*SALE*O3
23|Charlotte Aaaaaaaa|XXXX*SALE*O10
150|James Ggggggg|XXXX*SALE*O1
101|Connor Hhhhhhh|XXXX*SALE*O2
90|Barbara Iiiiiiii|XXXX*SALE*O2
23|Richard Ffffff|XXXX*DROP*O4
10|Holly Jjjjjjjj|XXXX*SALE*O5
90|Barbara Iiiiiii|XXXX*SALE*10
```

The code I currently have is:

```
$handle = fopen("lock.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    $i=1;
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $data = explode("|", $line);
        $locks = array($i, $data);
        $i++;
        var_dump($locks);

    }
    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
}
```

The output is currently:

```
array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "20" [1]=> string(14) "Charlotte Aaaa" [2]=> string(14) "XXXX*SALE*O9 " } } array(2) { [0]=> int(2) [1]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "60" [1]=> string(11) "Peggy Bbbbb" [2]=> string(14) "XXXX*SALE*O8 " } } array(2) { [0]=> int(3) [1]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "25" [1]=> string(12) "Ashley Ccccc" [2]=> string(14) "XXXX*SALE*O7 " } } array(2) { [0]=> int(4) [1]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(3) "103" [1]=> string(12) "Andrew Ddddd" [2]=> string(14) "XXXX*SALE*O1 " } } array(2) { [0]=> int(5) [1]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "51" [1]=> string(11) "Sally EEeee" [2]=> string(14) "XXXX*SALE*O6 " } } array(2) { [0]=> int(6) [1]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "9" [1]=> string(13) "Richard Fffff" [2]=> string(14) "XXXX*SALE*O3 " } } array(2) { [0]=> int(7) [1]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "23" [1]=> string(18) "Charlotte Aaaaaaaa" [2]=> string(15) "XXXX*SALE*O10 " } } array(2) { [0]=> int(8) [1]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(3) "150" [1]=> string(13) "James Ggggggg" [2]=> string(14) "XXXX*SALE*O1 " } } array(2) { [0]=> int(9) [1]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(3) "101" [1]=> string(14) "Connor Hhhhhhh" [2]=> string(14) "XXXX*SALE*O2 " } } array(2) { [0]=> int(10) [1]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "90" [1]=> string(16) "Barbara Iiiiiiii" [2]=> string(14) "XXXX*SALE*O2 " } } array(2) { [0]=> int(11) [1]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "23" [1]=> string(14) "Richard Ffffff" [2]=> string(14) "XXXX*DROP*O4 " } } array(2) { [0]=> int(12) [1]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "10" [1]=> string(14) "Holly Jjjjjjjj" [2]=> string(14) "XXXX*SALE*O5 " } } array(2) { [0]=> int(13) [1]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "90" [1]=> string(15) "Barbara Iiiiiii" [2]=> string(12) "XXXX*SALE*10" } }
```

What I would like to do is as follows, create an array which I can later use for an ajax search for the third part of each row

Therefore the array format would be

```
$locks[0][1] = 20
$locks[0][2] = Charlotte Aaaa
$locks[0][3] = XXXX*SALE*O9
```

I haven't looked at integrating ajax yet as I am failing at this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please demonstrate the array you want to have as a final result?

Comment: i've added it to the bottom

Comment: Can you show the formatted `var_dump()`, not all on one line?

Comment: Why are you starting your 2nd-level arrays at 1 instead of 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand from your desired output:
Basically inside the loop, instead of setting the output of the line ($data) as a value of the array. I set a sub-array for each row.

```
$locks = array();
$handle = fopen("lock.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    $i=0;
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $data = explode("|", $line);
        $locks[$i] = array(
            1 => $data[0],
            2 => $data[1],
            3 => $data[2]
        );
        $i++;
       //var_dump($locks);

    }
    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
}
```

Which should give the following:

```
$locks[0][1] = 20
$locks[0][2] = Charlotte Aaaa
$locks[0][3] = XXXX*SALE*O9
$locks[1][1] = 20
$locks[1][2] = Peggy Bbbbb
$locks[1][3] = XXXX*SALE*O8
... 
...
```

Comment: Why do you subtract 1 from `$i` instead of just starting it at 0?

Comment: thanks, works beautifully. I shall bear that in mind when doing it again.

Answer (score 1):

After you explode the line, push the array onto the resulting array:

```
$locks = array();
while ($line = fgets($handle)) {
    $line = trim($line); // remove the newline at the end
    $data = explode('|', $line);
    $locks[] = $data;
}
var_dump($locks);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you right then I think this should work and you'll got the data in array arr.

```
<?php

$arr=array();
$handle = fopen("lock.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    $i=1;
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $data = explode("|", $line);
        $locks = array($i, $data);
        $i++;
        //var_dump($locks);
        $arr[]=array(1=>$data[0],2=>$data[1],3=>$data[2]);
    }
    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.

}
?>
```